# Block IE and Opera using PHP

Tags: php, browser

I want to redirect user to a selected page if they use Any Version of IE or Opera. Because my website is using CSS 3 fully with different effects (animation effects) which are not supported by IE and Opera yet. 
I want to do it using PHP. Should the code bellow work?

```
if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) || preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
{ 
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/reject.html");
}
```

Or suggest me a better way please...

Comment: Though either of those browsers can spoof the useragent and still view your website.  I'd strongly suggest against redirecting out browsers simply because they don't support your CSS.  Personally I think your website should probably degrade gracefully for any browser.  Once you start singling some out you'll end up with unhappy users and potential maintainability problems down the road...

Comment: You are right, the website is still accessible though I used redirect. I'll downgrade css, but it'll take some time. Till then how can I tell the visitors to use supported browser?

Comment: Sadly but, 40% of the browser market belongs to IE. and know that IE is still the default browser that comes with many Windows machines. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers

Comment: Know that, but why I have to wait for a long time to get full css3 support from IE! So I decided to avoid it. LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
 if(preg_match('/MSIE|Opera/i',$u_agent))
 { 
      header("Location: http://www.example.com/reject.html");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this only with PHP. Browsers usually send a user agent string, but this can be spoofed quite easily. There is no way to be 100% sure of the browser the user is using, however the most reliable way to tell is with JavaScript. You can either write your own or do a quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20browser%20detection) and find a premade one.

Comment: I don't know Javascript at all. So I'll try to find out a solution by googling :)
Thanks for your suggestion.